# Successful Django Deploy Through AWS Elastic Beanstalk, But Getting 500 ERROR

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been stuck on this for the last week and I'm fairly lost as to what do for next steps.

I have a Django application that uses a MySQL database. I've deployed it using AWS Elastic Beanstalk using the following tutorial : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

It successfully deployed. However, I keep getting 500 errors when trying to access the site. I've also updated the host value as well.

Here's the error_log, but I'm not able to deduce much from it.

```
[Tue Jan 28 08:05:34.444677 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 3125] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Jan 28 08:05:34.460731 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 3125] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Tue Jan 28 08:05:34.460743 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 3125] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Tue Jan 28 08:05:34.461206 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 3125] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Tue Jan 28 08:05:34.461249 2020] [:warn] [pid 3125] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.
[Tue Jan 28 08:05:34.461253 2020] [:warn] [pid 3125] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.8.
[Tue Jan 28 08:05:34.463081 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3125] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jan 28 08:05:34.463096 2020] [core:notice] [pid 3125] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Tue Jan 28 08:06:21.350696 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3125] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jan 28 08:06:22.419261 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 4501] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Jan 28 08:06:22.435310 2020] [so:warn] [pid 4501] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Tue Jan 28 08:06:22.437572 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 4501] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Tue Jan 28 08:06:22.437582 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 4501] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Tue Jan 28 08:06:22.438217 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 4501] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Tue Jan 28 08:06:22.438283 2020] [:warn] [pid 4501] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.
[Tue Jan 28 08:06:22.438292 2020] [:warn] [pid 4501] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.8.
[Tue Jan 28 08:06:22.440572 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4501] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jan 28 08:06:22.440593 2020] [core:notice] [pid 4501] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Tue Jan 28 08:08:03.028260 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4501] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseEventLoop.__del__ of <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 526, in __del__
NameError: name 'ResourceWarning' is not defined
[Tue Jan 28 08:08:04.152017 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 4833] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Jan 28 08:08:04.168082 2020] [so:warn] [pid 4833] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Tue Jan 28 08:08:04.170245 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 4833] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Tue Jan 28 08:08:04.170256 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 4833] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Tue Jan 28 08:08:04.170793 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 4833] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Tue Jan 28 08:08:04.170852 2020] [:warn] [pid 4833] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.
[Tue Jan 28 08:08:04.170856 2020] [:warn] [pid 4833] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.8.
[Tue Jan 28 08:08:04.173067 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4833] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jan 28 08:08:04.173089 2020] [core:notice] [pid 4833] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Tue Jan 28 08:25:28.783035 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4833] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jan 28 08:25:32.859422 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 5573] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Jan 28 08:25:32.875584 2020] [so:warn] [pid 5573] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Tue Jan 28 08:25:32.877541 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 5573] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Tue Jan 28 08:25:32.877552 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 5573] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Tue Jan 28 08:25:32.878103 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 5573] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Tue Jan 28 08:25:32.878167 2020] [:warn] [pid 5573] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.
[Tue Jan 28 08:25:32.878174 2020] [:warn] [pid 5573] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.8.
[Tue Jan 28 08:25:32.880448 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5573] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jan 28 08:25:32.880477 2020] [core:notice] [pid 5573] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Wed Jan 29 01:11:07.166917 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5573] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseEventLoop.__del__ of <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 526, in __del__
NameError: name 'ResourceWarning' is not defined
[Wed Jan 29 01:11:08.333254 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 28706] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Jan 29 01:11:08.349662 2020] [so:warn] [pid 28706] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Wed Jan 29 01:11:08.351804 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 28706] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Wed Jan 29 01:11:08.351813 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 28706] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Wed Jan 29 01:11:08.352386 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 28706] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Jan 29 01:11:08.352447 2020] [:warn] [pid 28706] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.
[Wed Jan 29 01:11:08.352451 2020] [:warn] [pid 28706] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.8.
[Wed Jan 29 01:11:08.354766 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28706] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jan 29 01:11:08.354783 2020] [core:notice] [pid 28706] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

If anyone could provide some insight/help/further steps, it would be greatly appreciated. I can provide more logs, etc anything else that would help. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure, maybe you can try with Debug True and see if what the error might be.

Comment: This seems like a problem related to your `wsgi` or `asgi` module. Are you running your django workers using `gunicorn` or something similar? If you are using `gunicorn`, are you using a sync worker or something async, like `gevent`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing the ssl module on your ec2 : sudo yum install mod_ssl for your httpd issue.

Also, if you are using a load balancer, you might want to check the health status of your targets. When the health checks fail, you get 500 errors.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't do anything. I'm still getting a 500 error when trying to load my site.

Comment: What exactly is the error? Is it 503 or 502? Or something else? Also, u might want to inspect your page on the browser when u hit the url.

Comment: It literally says "Server Error (500)".

Comment: Well 500 generally specifies an internal server error. You might want to check your code for any exception. May be you can put a try..except block and debug it that way.

Answer (score 0):

From your log, I think this is the culprit:

```py
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseEventLoop.__del__ of <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 526, in __del__
```

I checked the file `/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py` and found something similar to this:

```py
    def __del__(self):
        if not self.is_closed():
            warnings.warn(f"unclosed event loop {self!r}", ResourceWarning,
                          source=self)
            if not self.is_running():
                self.close()
```

Seems like you're deleting the event loop without calling `close` before.

(`ResourceWarning` is a built-in class, I'm not sure why it's undefined though)